# Golang libphonenumber

Tags: go, libphonenumber

How can I get the country code number by passing the number in golang by using this library:
https://godoc.org/github.com/nyaruka/phonenumbers?

Comment: You're not writing syntactically valid Go.

Comment: Most basic syntax questions are answered within the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org) which only takes a few minutes to finish.

Comment: It looks like this is a machine-generated port of a Java library, complete with Java examples. This is why it's not working--you're trying to write Java in Go.

Comment: I understand that the syntax is not valid for golang, but this is what i found in library documentation: https://godoc.org/github.com/nyaruka/phonenumbers, i'm just beginner in golang that's why i was thinking that maybe i'm missing something.

Comment: So what is your question? You seem to be asking why that code doesn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer which I was looking is how to get the country code by passing the phone number only, this is the solution which is working perfectly.

```
num, err := phonenumbers.Parse("+123456789", "")

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
}

regionNumber := phonenumbers.GetRegionCodeForNumber(num)
countryCode := phonenumbers.GetCountryCodeForRegion(regionNumber)
fmt.Println(countryCode)
```

Thank you Yacacov for the hint ;)